# Кик из голосового канала Discrod (DSharpplus)

Tags: c#, discord

Доброго всем времени суток.
Как кикнуть человека из голосового канала с помощью DSharpplus? 
В Api Documentation нашел только `public Task PlaceMemberAsync(DiscordMember member)` или же `public Task PlaceInAsync(DiscordChannel channel)`
`await Member.PlaceInAsync(null)` не помогает 
https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/api/index.html 
Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать `Task.DiscordMember.ModifyAsync(Action<MemberEditModel> action)`
К примеру,

```
[Command("kick")]
public async Task Move(CommandContext ctx, DiscordMember Member)
{
    wait Member.ModifyAsync(delegate (MemberEditModel Kick)
    {
        Kick.VoiceChannel = null;
    });
}
```